# retrieve config data in java properties file from web service

Tags: java, web-services, properties-file

I need your advice about the best way to retreive config data which is stored within a java properties file from jersey web services to use them in several DAO classes called by those web services.

The solution that I implement is as follow:

- create a java properties file and put in it all properties that I need
- all the java properties file in an application listener and put properties in servletcontext attribute
- in a web service, I retreive properties by injecting an instance on servletContext using @Context annotation and I pass them to any DAO function's methodes that need them.

So is it a good approach? If not, could you suggest me another solution?

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting individual property as attribute to context put property object in context and from that prop object get the properties where required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a Singleton class in which you read your propertie file , 
and then create an applicationLister by implmenting ServletContextListener@contextInitialized method and call getInstance of your class (this step is not mandatory , so you can left it, it's just to instantiate the singleton at the start of the app container ),

Adter in your whole project just call the satic method YouClass.getInstance() and acces your Properties.

By example :

```
public class MyPropertieFileReader {

    private static MyPropertieFileReader instance = null;
    private Properties properties;


    protected MyPropertieFileReader() throws IOException{

        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path-to-property-file.properties"));

    }

    public static MyPropertieFileReader getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            try {
                instance = new TestDataProperties();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

In your WS , just call

```
MyPropertieFileReader.getInstance().getProperty("property-name");
```

hope this will help .